# ng-click Filter Comparing Two JSON Arrays

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I am trying to create an Angular filter on a radio button via ng-click that compares two seperate JSON objects and returns the object if the value is the same within a ng-repeat list.

Right now I am pulling in an event Api that returns an object that looks something like this -

**Event API-**

```
[{
"instructor_id": 502,
"datetime": "2014-12-07T00:30:00.000Z",
"end_time": "2014-12-07T01:00:00.000Z"
}, {
"instructor_url": 510,
"datetime": "2015-01-20T16:00:00.000Z",
"end_time": "2015-01-20T16:45:00.000Z"
}]
```

And I also have a separate Api that pulls in a list of the user's favorite instructor's and returns that favorited instructor's id, like this

**Favorite Instructor API**

```
[{
"user_id": 510
}, {
"user_id": 506
}]
```

I can get the filter to work if I just hard code in the instructor_id to a filter like so -

```
<input type="radio" ng-click="instructor_url = {instructor_url: '510}"/>
```

and then running the filter on my ng-repeat list

```
<li ng-repeat="event in events | filter:instructor_url">
```

But obviously this isn't what I'm looking for.  I want to be able to call a function that matches them and returns only the events where the instuctor_id from the Event API match the user_is from the Favorite Instructor API.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please see demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.events = [{
    "instructor_url": 506,
    "datetime": "2014-12-07T00:30:00.000Z",
    "end_time": "2014-12-07T01:00:00.000Z"
  }, {
    "instructor_url": 510,
    "datetime": "2015-01-20T16:00:00.000Z",
    "end_time": "2015-01-20T16:45:00.000Z"
  }];


  $scope.FavoriteInstructor = [{
    "user_id": 510
  }, {
    "user_id": 506
  }];



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">


    <label ng-repeat="user in FavoriteInstructor" ng-init="i= $parent">{{user.user_id}}
      <input type="radio" name="instructor" ng-model="i.instructor_url" ng-value="user.user_id" />
    </label>
    <label>all  <input type="radio" name="instructor" ng-model="instructor_url" ng-value="" /></label>
    <hr/>
    <p>Events</p>
    <hr/>
    <li ng-repeat="event in events | filter:instructor_url">
      <h3>Instructor Url:{{event.instructor_url}}</h3>
      <p>{{event.datetime | date:short}}-{{event.end_time | date :short}}</p>
    </li>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you @sylwester

What if I want to just have one radio button that filters the list for all favorites instructors?